# Replace string in all files of a folder with powershell

Tags: powershell

I've just started using Powershell because I need to make a script that puts links in all files (htm files) of a folder. These links actually link all the files between them.
I have a list of the files that are in the folder (this file is called `list.txt` and contains the name of the files without the extension)

In each file I want to make following changes:

From:

> `<tspan x="53" y="54.8">Surveillance_Err_PRG</tspan>`

To:

> `<tspan x="53" y="54.8"><a href="C:/[...path...]/HTMs/Surveillance_Err_PRG.htm">Surveillance_Err_PRG</a></tspan>`

After some research, I wrote following code, but it does nothing (the output just display my code):

```
$directory = "C:\Users\jacka\Desktop\Organigramme_PLC_prog_test\"
$list = "$directory" + "list.txt"
$htms = "$directory" + "HTMs"   

$htmFiles = Get-ChildItem $directory *.htm -rec
foreach ($file in $htmFiles)
{
    foreach($line in Get-Content $list)
    {
        if($line -match $regex)
        {
            $fichier = "$htms\"+"$line"+".htm"

            (Get-Content $file.PSPath) |
            Foreach-Object { $_ -replace "$line", "<a href=""$htms\$line"">$line</a>" } |
            Set-Content $file.PSPath
         }
         echo $fichier
    }
}
```

Before that, I had it like this:

```
foreach($line in Get-Content $list) {
    if($line -match $regex){
        $fichier = "$htms\"+"$line"+".htm"
        (Get-Content $fichier).replace("$line", "<a href=""$fichier"">$line</a>") | Set-Content $fichier
        echo $fichier
    }
}
```

It doesn't really work since it just puts a link on the inner title (in each htm there is the name of the document displayed on the top).

So there is a lot of information I know (but I wanted to give as much information as I could) and I'm sorry if I wasn't clear but basically I want to make the code above work for every file in my folder.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In you TO, there is a path. Is that coming from a variable or are you gonna hard code that ?

Comment: @RanadipDutta in my TO ?

Comment: In your "`To:

<tspan x="53" y="54.8"><a href="C:/[...path...]/HTMs/Surveillance_Err_PRG.htm">Surveillance_Err_PRG</a></tspan>`" -- What is the path ? Dynamic or static

Comment: [It's not recommended to use regex to parse html](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5039142). Instead consider [loading the file as html](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24989452/5039142) and [manipulating the html object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa219325(v=office.11).aspx) - I suspect you need `CreateElement`

Comment: @RanadipDutta Oh ok I did that because it is static so yes I hard code this for the moment because I'm still testing the code

Comment: @gms0ulman Thank you I'll try that but won't I get the same issues since I don't really know how to edit all the files in the folder ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found the solution

First, I had a problem there

```
$htmFiles = Get-ChildItem $directory *.htm -rec
    foreach ($file in $configFiles)
```

The variables weren't the same but then I got this error :

```
C:\Users\jacka\Desktop\Organigramme_PLC_prog_test\HTMs\Systeme_Filtration_Prg.htm
Get-Content : Impossible de trouver le chemin d'accès « C:\Users\jacka\ChargementProg_PRG.htm », car il n'existe pas.
Au caractère Ligne:22 : 14
+             (Get-Content $file) |
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\jacka\ChargementProg_PRG.htm:String) [Get-Content], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
```

I solved this issue by adding .FullName after $file which prevented [Get-Content trying to access the file from current directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47923050/7862279) :

```
$htmFiles = Get-ChildItem $directory *.htm -rec
foreach ($file in $htmFiles)
{

    foreach($line in Get-Content $list)
    {
        if($line -match $regex)
        {
            $fichier = "$directory"+"$line"+".htm"
            if ($file.FullName -ne $fichier) #to prevent header to be changed
            {
                (Get-Content $file.FullName) |
                Foreach-Object { $_ -replace "$line", "<a href=""$fichier"">$line</a>" } |
                Set-Content $file.FullName
            }
         }
    }
    echo "$file.FullName is done"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you did not include the whole files I have create a simple `source.html` file:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Website</title>
</head>
<body>
<tspan x="53" y="54.8">Surveillance_Err_PRG</tspan>
</body>
</html>
```

Next the issue you have is to parse **HTML**.  As noted in the comments regexp are **NOT** a good way to parse html.  In my eyes if you have a fairly complex html page/website etc.  the best solution is to use [html agility pack](http://html-agility-pack.net) which is originally for *.NET* but it can be adjusted for powershell too.

For your example to get the final result you would have to do it like this:
(note: **Don't forget** to change your path to the *HtmlAgilityPack.dll*)

```
Add-Type -Path 'C:\prg_sdk\nuget\HtmlAgilityPack.1.7.2\lib\Net40-client\HtmlAgilityPack.dll'

$doc = New-Object HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
$result = $doc.Load('C:\prg\PowerShell\test\SO\source.html')

$text = $doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tspan").InnerHTML
write-host $text

$out_text = $doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tspan").OuterHTML
write-host $out_text

$element = $doc.CreateTextNode("<a href=""c:\<your_path>\HTMs\$text.htm"">$text</a>")
$doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//tspan").InnerHTML = $element.InnerText

$changed_text = $doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//tspan").OuterHTML
Write-host "Adjusted text:" $changed_text

write-host 'whole HTML:' $doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//tspan").OuterHtml

# To overview whole HTML
write-host 'whole HTML:' $doc.DocumentNode.InnerHTML
```

The write host will produce your wished:

`<tspan x="53" y="54.8"><a href="c:\<your_path>\HTMs\Surveillance_Err_PRG.htm">Surveillance_Err_PRG</a></tspan>`

To find a string in a file you could do something like this (just a snippet):

```
$html_files= Get-ChildItem . *.htm -rec
foreach ($file in $html_files)
{
    (Get-Content $file.PSPath) |
    Foreach-Object { $_ -replace "$out_text", "$changed_text" } |
    Set-Content $file.PSPath
}
```

To put it together you will have to loop via all the `.htm` files and replace it with above examples.  If you want us complete it you would have to give me whole file example.  I have done it on testing one:

Now all togeter it looks like this:

```
Add-Type -Path 'C:\prg_sdk\nuget\HtmlAgilityPack.1.7.2\lib\Net40-client\HtmlAgilityPack.dll'

$doc = New-Object HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
$result = $doc.Load('C:\prg\PowerShell\test\SO\source.html')

$text = $doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tspan").InnerHTML

$original_tag = $doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tspan").OuterHTML

$element = $doc.CreateTextNode("<a href=""c:\<your_path>\HTMs\$text.htm"">$text</a>")
$doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//tspan").InnerHTML = $element.InnerText

$changed_tag = $doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//tspan").OuterHTML

$html_files= Get-ChildItem . *.htm -rec
foreach ($file in $html_files)
{
    (Get-Content $file.PSPath) |
    Foreach-Object { $_ -replace "$original_tag", "$changed_tag" } |
    Set-Content $file.PSPath
}
```

I hope that the source code is clear, I have tried to make it readable (don't forget to change all the variables).

Comment: Thank you ! That's a very complete answer, I don't understand everything at the moment but I'll dig into it to fully understand how this works ! Thank you for the time you took !

Comment: @JackA: please take your time digging into it.  If you have questions don't hesitate to ask.  When you think it answers your question don't forget to accept the answer - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers